# 2D Array containing Arrays

Tags: java, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on a discrete math problem in Java where I'm trying to find r-permutations up to n with repetition. This means if r = 4, n = 2 we can have:
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
1 1 2 1
1 1 2 2, etc.
Repetition means 1112 is a unique combination, however 1211 is not because 1112 already contains 3 1's and 1 2.
Therefore I wrote code to iterate through all the permutations, and every iteration is stored in an array. There is a "Master Array" which I planned on being a 2D Array where the first dimension are all unique arrays or permutations. Therefore all I have to do is create a temp array of the new iteration and use Arrays.sort and compare the temp array to all the indexes in the master array (this works because 1211, 1112, 2111, and 1121 all sort to 1112 in ascending order).
Now, the problem I'm having is storing these arrays into the 2D array Masterkey.
I've tried:
Masterkey[count] = array;, but when I print(Masterkey[count][0]) only a single integer is being output rather than the array. (array is the newest permutation)
Masterkey[count] = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);, once again prints a single integer rather than the array.
Masterkey[count] = array.clone();, also prints out just an integer.
I may be overlooking something simple, but I'm just struggling to get array to be stored in Masterkey.

Answer (score 1):

`Masterkey[count][0]` will always print a single integer because `Masterkey[count] = array`. so `Masterkey[count][0]` is the same as `array[0]`. However, if you assign `array` to `Masterkey[count][0]` it will print the array.

Comment: Wouldn't Masterkey[count][0] look for an int rather than an array, therefore not work? Just tried it and it said to convert array to type int

Comment: Because, I guessing here but most likely you initialized `Masterkey` as an int array. You just need to redeclare it to have array of ints and not just ints.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the notation for declaring Masterkey into an array of ints rather than just ints?

Comment: it is just double brackets like `int[][] Masterkey`. If you post a code sample, it might be easier to help

Comment: double perm = (factorial(n+r-1))/( factorial(r)*factorial(n-1));
int[][] Masterkey = new int[(int) perm][1];
This is how it's initialized. Perm is just the combinatoric equation with repetition.